# Recharts: Hide Bar where value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, bar-chart, recharts

I have a Recharts `BarChart` component with 3 different values for each day of the week: `primary`, `secondary`, and `tertiary`. In some cases `secondary` and `tertiary` have no data. If there is no data, I'd like for the specific `Bar` components mapped to those keys to not render at all on those specific days, however I'm struggling to find any way of doing this.

I'm using the `BarChart` like so:

```js
<BarChart
  width={700}
  height={500}
  data={data}
>
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
  <YAxis />
  <Bar dataKey="primary" fill="#009734" />
  <Bar dataKey="secondary" fill="#D97800" />
  <Bar dataKey="tertiary" fill="#C1BEBE" />
</BarChart>
```

This is what my data currently looks like:

```js
[{
  name: 'Tue',
  primary: 8,
}, {
  name: 'Wed',
  primary: 7,
  secondary: 5,
}, {
  name: 'Thu',
  primary: 12,
  secondary: 9,
  tertiary: 7,
}]
```

When rendered, I see this:

[image: BarChart Example 1]

However I'd much rather not have those value-less bars added to the chart at all so that the other data is moved over to be more centrally-aligned and the daily plots get moved closer together:

[image: Modified BarChart]

That is a crude image edit, but I think it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

Is there some way I can achieve this with Recharts?

Comment: How did you resolve it?  I also have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Recharts doesn't support this option right now.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1265) from 2 years ago that was most likely misunderstood by the people who answered (the op wants to hide bars like you - conditional on the missing data not the entire Bar like the "hide" property or reducing the data would allow).